# Irreducible in $S^{-1}R$ implies numerator irreducible in R?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, unique-factorization-domains

I would like to prove the following;

Let $R$ be UFD and $S \subset R$, $S$ is multiplicative, $1_R \in S$.

> Claim: If $r/s$ is irreducible in $S^{-1}R$ then there exists $r'/s'$ s.t $r/s\sim r'/s'$ and $r'$ is irreducible in R.

I feel like it should be true, but simply playing with elements has gotten me nowhere.

Comment: and you're trying to show that if $r/s$ is irreducible in $S^{-1}R$, then $r$ is irreducible in $R$?

Comment: Not quite; but basically.

Comment: because r/s is many different elements in $R \times S$

Comment: Like take $R$ to be integers and $S$ powers of 2. Then $3/2$ is irreducible but 3/2=6/4 and $6$ is clearly not irreducible.

Comment: I see; I hope you don't mind I've edited it to highlight the statement